# How to select all records having an attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-activerecord

I'm using rails4 with paperclip. On one of my forms I would like to list only the  records of a resource having a paperclips attachment. Is there any built in support for this in paperclip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

`YourModel.where.not(attachment_file_name: nil)`